# Lex bot should not accept only integers

Tags: bots, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have created an Amazon Lex bot that offers several services:

1. open a case
2. check status
3. status via email

[welcome intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CquiQ.png)

In the first option, we open a case that requires a reason against which we are opening a case.
My bot receives all values as reasons even if the user gives some number it adds the number as a reason.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFskB.png)

The only thing I want to do is that I just want to prevent my bot to accept only integer values. If my bot accepts reasons like "broken laptop" or "internet issue" that is fine.

Comment: can you provide us with the code you made so far so we can help you ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the `AMAZON.AlphaNumeric` type as your slot type. Combined with a Lambda function, you can then validate the user's input and respond accordingly based on whether the user inputs a number or a string of text.